# Can I iterate through variable in subscript?

Tags: python

Sorry I'm not really sure how to ask this question, but what I need to do is ask for a variable n and print something like this:

x<sub>1</sub>

x<sub>2</sub>

..

x<sub>n</sub>

I saw that there is something like \u208x, but it seems like x needs to be changed manually.
So is this possible to do? Also I cant't use any libraries that have to be downloaded. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Does this implies you only use the `print` function / printing on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create your list of subscript notations (to distinguish from the nomenclature of the term "variable" in the context of programming, since you seem to want to "print" a list of them out), and create a translation table that's compatible with the built-in [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) with what you want to convert.  The conversion table for the unicode codepoints for the number `0` to `9` are in the range between `\u0030` and `\u003a` to their corresponding subscript version found in `\u2080` to `\u208a` can be created by zipping the two ranges together and form a `dict` like so:

```
translations = dict(zip(range(0x30, 0x3a), range(0x2080, 0x208a)))
```

If the conversion of the `U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N` (aka `n`) into `LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER N` (aka `ₙ`) is also desired, just update the translation table with their corresponding codepoints like so:

```
translations.update({0x6e: 0x2099})
```

Now if you have a list of strings that represent the subscript notations that you are interested in (e.g. generated programmatically), the following demonstrates the original output along with the translated output:

```
notations = [f'x{i}' for i in range(15)]
for notation in notations:
    translated = notation.translate(translations)
    print(f'{notation} -> {translated}')

print(f'xn -> {"xn".translate(translations)}')
```

Should produce the following output

```
x0 -> x₀
x1 -> x₁
x2 -> x₂
x3 -> x₃
x4 -> x₄
x5 -> x₅
x6 -> x₆
x7 -> x₇
x8 -> x₈
x9 -> x₉
x10 -> x₁₀
x11 -> x₁₁
x12 -> x₁₂
x13 -> x₁₃
x14 -> x₁₄
xn -> xₙ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\u208x` idea like this:

```py
start = ord("\u2080") # subscript zero

for subscript in range(10):
  character = chr(start + subscript)
  print(subscript, "->", character)
```

output:

```
0 -> ₀
1 -> ₁
2 -> ₂
3 -> ₃
4 -> ₄
5 -> ₅
6 -> ₆
7 -> ₇
8 -> ₈
9 -> ₉
```

The `ord` and `chr` functions convert characters to and from their unicode point number, respectively.

Comment: This will only work for a single digit. If you have a number greater than 9, split it into individual digits then concatenate the result together. This is a very common exercise and you can find lots of information about it online.